# How can i get the multiple .dat files in particular path in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

`var filepath =../project/e2e/*.dat`,

By using this I am able to get one file at a time but I need to fetch multiple files.

Instead of using this path to get the file, is there any other way to get multiple `.dat` files in the same path?

Comment: your `filepath` variable is only holding the path to the files. Where that is being called is what matters so could you show that?

Comment: var path = require('path');
var fileToUpload = '/home/innova/Project/se_profile_UI/e2e/jsonfile/OUTZ-DABAINKA0001-2HiThGdyYanASgj2hthXX5gS9-20200423-000-00.dat',
absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath);
in this code  i give one .dat filename directly to upload ,but i want to fetch multiple .dat files

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you can share more details, like how are you fetching the files.

Though try this

```
const path = require('path'); //at global level

let filepath = '../project/e2e/*.dat';
let absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, filepath); // This will resolve the absolute path
```

Comment: var path = require('path');
var fileToUpload = '/home/innova/Project/se_profile_UI/e2e/jsonfile/OUTZ-DABAINKA0001-2HiThGdyYanASgj2hthXX5gS9-20200423-000-00.dat',
absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);

Comment: I tried the same code ,it is working fine but through this code i can able to get one .dat file at the time.i need to fetch multiple .dat files at the time .

Comment: I think first to get the count of files in the directory and then start a loop for that count.

var fs = require('fs'); 
fs.readdir( 'path/to/your/folder', (error, files) => { 
   let totalFiles = files.length; // return the number of files
   console.log(totalFiles); // print the total number of files
});